# Is Mahalanobis distance equivalent to the Euclidean one on the PCA-rotated data?

Tags: r, pca, distance, multivariate-normal-distribution, rotation

I've been led to believe (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24221/mahalanobis-distance-via-pca-when-np) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance)) that Mahalanobis distance is the same as the Euclidean distance on the PCA-rotated data.  In other words, taking multivariate normal data $X$, the Mahalanobis distance of all of the $x$'s from any given point (say $\mathbf{0}$) should be the same as the Euclidean distance of the entries of $X^{rot}$ from $\mathbf{0}$, where $X^{rot}$ is the product of the data and the PCA rotation matrix.

**1.  Is this true?**

My code below is suggesting to me that it is not.  In particular, it looks like the variance of the Mahalanobis distance around the PCA-Euclidean distance is increasing in the magnitude of the PCA-Euclidean distance.  Is this a coding error, or a feature of the universe?  Does it have to do with imprecision in an estimate of something? Something that gets squared?

```
N=1000
cr = runif(1,min=-1,max=1)
A = matrix(c(1,cr,cr,1),2)
e<-mvrnorm(n = N,rep(0,2),A)
mx = apply(e, 2, mean)
sx = apply(e, 2, sd)
e = t(apply(e,1,function(X){(X-mx)/sx}))
plot(e[,1],e[,2])
dum<-rep(0,2)
md = mahalanobis(e,dum,cov(e))

pc = prcomp(e,center=F,scale=F)
d<-as.matrix(dist(rbind(dum,pc$x),method='euclidean',diag=F))
d<-d[1,2:ncol(d)]
plot(d,md^.5)
abline(0,1)
```

**2.  If the answer to the above is true, can one use the PCA-rotated Euclidean distance as a stand-in for the Mahalanobis distance when $p>n$?**

If not, is there a similar metric that captures multivariate distance, scaled by correlation, and for which distributional results exist to allow the calculation of the probability of an observation?

**EDIT**
I've run a few simulations to investigate the equivalence of MD and SED on scaled/rotated data over a gradient of n and p.  As I mentioned previously, I'm interested in the probability of an observation.  I am hoping to find a good way to get the probability of an observation being part of a multivariate normal distribution, but for which I've got $n<p$ data to estimate the distribution.  See the code below.  It looks like the PCA-scaled/rotated SED is *slightly* biased estimator of the MD, with a fair amount of variance that seems to stop increasing when $p=N$.

```
f = function(N=1000,n,p){
  a = runif(p^2,-1,1)
  a = matrix(a,p)
  S = t(a)%*%a
  x = mvrnorm(N,rep(0,p),S)
  mx = apply(x, 2, mean)
  sx = apply(x, 2, sd)
  x = t(apply(x,1,function(X){(X-mx)/sx}))
  Ss = solve(cov(x))
  x = x[sample(1:N,n,replace=F),]
  md = mahalanobis(x,rep(0,p),Ss,inverted=T)
  prMD<-pchisq(md,df = p) 
  pc = prcomp(x,center=F,scale=F)
  d<-mahalanobis(scale(pc$x),rep(0,ncol(pc$x)),diag(rep(1,ncol(pc$x))))
  prPCA<-pchisq(d,df = min(p,n))#N is the number of PCs where N<P 
  return(data.frame(prbias = as.numeric(mean(prMD - prPCA)), prvariance = as.numeric(mean((prMD - prPCA)^2))))
}

grid = data.frame(n=100,p=2:200)
grid$prvariance <-grid$prbias <-NA

for (i in 1:nrow(grid)){
    o = f(n=grid[i,]$n,p=grid[i,]$p)
    grid[i,3:4]<-o
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
with(grid, plot(p,prbias))
abline(v=100)
m = lm(prbias~p,data=grid)
abline(m,col='red',lty=2)
with(grid, plot(p,prvariance))
abline(v=100)
```

[image]

Two questions: 
1.  Any criticism of what I'm finding in these simulations?
2.  Can anyone formalize what I'm finding with an analytical expression for the bias and the variance as functions of n and p?  I'd accept an answer that does this.

Comment: From the very formula of Mahalanobis distance it follows that it is equal to Euclidean distance when the covariance matrix is identity matrix (or, to extend without loss of key - proportional to identity). Unless data are exactly spherical the covariances between their PCs are diagonal, not identity, matrix.

Comment: To note, PCA doesn't just rotate the data it also scales it differently in different directions. Scaling has an effect on distance measurements.

Comment: Squared Mahalanobis distances between the data points are exactly proportional to the _weighted_ squared Euclidean distances computed on the principal components of the data. The weight being `1/eigenvalue` of the component. (And same hold also when we speak about distances between points and centroid, instead of point-point distances) This weighting is what compensates for the differences between Mahalanobis and Euclidean which I have touched in my comment.

Comment: @ttnphns That could be an answer for the first part of my question.  I'm still thinking about the second part however -- whether it is a good stand-in for mahalanobis when $P>N$.  I'm thinking however that the curse of dimensionality might start becoming pretty severe.

Comment: You can search this site `Mahalanobis singular` which might yield answers to your second question

Comment: Hi, @generic_user! I am wondering if you had a chance to take a look at my answer below. Don't hesitate to ask if something remains unclear.

Comment: Hi Amoeba, I saw and upvoted your answer.  You basically echoed what ttnphns said, when s/he reminded me about the scaling by the eigenvalues.  But I'm still looking for a good way to think about how to interpret the euclidian distance on the transformed space when $n<p$.  It seems sketchy, but I'm still just going on intuition.

Comment: I have updated my answer to your Q2, please take a look. If this is not satisfying, I encourage you to edit your question to clarify your Q2, perhaps you can try to explain what is bothering you here and what remains unclear.

Comment: Interesting edit. If your code produces some figure(s), could you maybe insert them in your question? Not everybody is an R user...

Comment: @generic_user. Thank you. Can you please explain what is the meaning of Mahalanobis distance in the principal component space? Is it different from Mahalanobis distance in the original data space? What advantages we would have for having Mahalanobis distance in either of the spaces?

Answer (score 13):

Mahalanobis distance is equivalent to the Euclidean distance on the PCA-transformed data (not just PCA-rotated!), where by "PCA-transformed" I mean (i) first rotated to become uncorrelated, and (ii) then scaled to  become standardized. This is what @ttnphns said in the comments above and what both @DmitryLaptev and @whuber meant and explicitly wrote in their answers that you linked to ([one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24221) and [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092)), so I encourage you to re-read their answers and make sure this point becomes clear.

**This means that you can make your code work simply by replacing `pc$x` with `scale(pc$x)` in the fourth line from the bottom.**

Regarding your second question, with $n<p$, covariance matrix is singular and hence Mahalanobis distance is undefined. Indeed, think about Euclidean distance in the PCA-transformed data; when $n<p$, some of the eigenvalues of covariance matrix are zero and the corresponding PCs have zero variance (all the data points are projected to zero). It is therefore impossible to standardize these PCs, as it is impossible to divide by zero. Mahalanobis distance cannot be defined "in these directions".

What one can do, is to focus exclusively on the subspace where the data actually lie, and define Mahalanobis distance in this subspace. This is equivalent to doing PCA and keeping only non-zero components, which is I think what you suggested in your question #2. So the answer to this is yes. I am not sure though how useful this can be in practice, as this distance is likely to be very unstable (near-zero eigenvalues are known with very bad precision, but are going to be inverted in the Mahalanobis formula, possible yielding gross errors).

Answer (score 3):

Mahalanobis distance is the scaled Euclidean distance when the covariance matrix is diagonal. In PCA the covariance matrix between components is diagonal. The scaled Euclidean distance is the Euclidean distance where the variables were scaled by their standard deviations. See p.303 in [Encyclopedia of Distances](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjABahUKEwiLu6TYzLPHAhWJGR4KHf5VBDs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uco.es%2Fusers%2Fma1fegan%2FComunes%2Fasignaturas%2Fvision%2FEncyclopedia-of-distances-2009.pdf&ei=vqbTVYvkAYmzeP6rkdgD&usg=AFQjCNF4o7nokMwQzttiCeRyDMi3ZwX4hw&sig2=8dAjKt6-ffRe9cQ1zrYQOw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.dmo), an very useful book, btw.

It seems that you're trying to use Euclidean distance on the subset of factors of PCA. You probably reduced dimensionality using PCA. You can do it, but there will be some error introduced which is "proportional" to the proportion of variance that is explained by your PCA components. You'll also have to adjust the distance for the scale (i.e. variances explained), of course.